# How to take data from an API and create a chart on that using Chart.js and Angular 8?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, api, chart.js

I'm new to Angular 8 and I'm currently working on a personal project to create a chart on a weather API using Chart.js. I have created a new component called weather.
This is the API link 
https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/history/city?q=Warren,OH&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22

Here is the data taken from the API:

```
{ "message":"",
"cod":"200",
"city_id":2643743,
"calctime":0.0875,
"cnt":3,
"list": [
    { "main": { 
        "temp": 279.946, 
        "temp_min":279.946, 
        "temp_max":279.946, 
        "pressure":1016.76, 
        "sea_level":1024.45, 
        "grnd_level":1016.76, 
        "humidity":100
    }, // etc
```

My weather.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-weather',
  templateUrl: './weather.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./weather.component.css']
})
export class WeatherComponent implements OnInit {

  weather:Object;
  constructor(private data: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() 
  {
    this.data.getWeather().subscribe(data=>{
      this.weather=data;
      console.log(this.weather);
    });
  }

  public barChartOptions={
    scaleShowVerticalLines:false,
    responsive:true
  };
  public barChartLabels=[this.weather.list[0].main,this.weather.list[1].main,this.weather.list[2].main];
  public barChartType="bar";
  public barChartLegend="true";
  public barChartData=[
    {data:[this.weather.list[0].main.temp,this.weather.list[1].main.temp,this.weather.list[2].main.temp],label:'Temperature'},
    {data:[this.weather.list[0].main.pressure,this.weather.list[1].main.pressure,this.weather.list[2].main.pressure],label:'Pressure'},
    {data:[this.weather.list[0].main.sea_level,this.weather.list[1].main.sea_level,this.weather.list[2].main.sea_level],label:'Sea Level'}
  ];
}
```

I'm finding it difficult to extract various data elements from the API. They are present in a list array in the API and I'm not sure how to get the individual elements of the array.
Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: There's a lot of code here, but it seems like your question is about parsing an array correct? Can you just give an example of the data you need to parse, and leave out any code that isn't absolutely necessary?

Comment: @DanielSchroederDev Yes I have edited the question. Please take a look. Thanks.

Comment: Which part do you want to extract, and why is it difficult?

Comment: I want to take temperature, sea level and pressure from array main, which is a part of another array called list. Array list has 3 entries of main. I'm having trouble extracting that data.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Array.prototype.map()`:

```
public barChartLabels = this.weather.list.map(item => item.main);

public barChartData = [
    {
        data: this.weather.list.map(item => item.main.temp),
        label: 'Temperature',
    },
    {
        data: this.weather.list.map(item => item.main.pressure),
        label: 'Pressure',
    },
    {
        data: this.weather.list.map(item => item.main.sea_level),
        label: 'Sea Level'
    },
];
```

If you are only using the `list` property of the `data`, you could change this assignment:

```
this.weather = data
```

To:

```
this.weather = data.list
```

And shorten the `map()` calls to:

```
public barChartLabels = this.weather.map(item => item.main);

public barChartData = [
    {
        data: this.weather.map(item => item.main.temp),
        label: 'Temperature',
    },
    {
        data: this.weather.map(item => item.main.pressure),
        label: 'Pressure',
    },
    {
        data: this.weather.map(item => item.main.sea_level),
        label: 'Sea Level'
    },
];
```